# What is the LINQ to XML equivalent for this XPath

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xpath

I wondering what the "best practice" way (in C#) is to implement this xpath query with LINQ:

```
/topNode/middleNode[@filteringAttribute='filterValue']/penultimateNode[@anotherFilterAttribute='somethingElse']/nodesIWantReturned
```

I would like an IEnumerable list of the 'nodesIWantReturned', but only from a certain section of the XML tree, dependent on the value of ancestor attributes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use XPath with XElement or LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642829/how-to-use-xpath-with-xelement-or-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more *verbal* solution:

```
var nodesIWantReturned = from m in doc.Elements("topNode").Elements("middleNode")
              from p in m.Elements("penultimateNode")
              from n in p.Elements("nodesIWantReturned")
              where m.Attribute("filteringAttribute").Value == "filterValue"
              where p.Attribute("anotherFilterAttribute").Value == "somethingElse"
              select n;
```

Comment: This won't work correctly. It'll throw a NullReferenceException if an element is encountered that lacks the attribute.

Answer (score 10):

In addition to the Linq methods shown, you can also import the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace and then use the [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) extension method to use your XPath query directly.

It is noted in the class that these methods are slower than 'proper' Linq-to-XML, however a lot of the time this isn't too important, and sometimes it's easier just to use XPath (it's certainly a lot terser!).

```
var result = doc.XPathSelectElements("your xpath here");
```

Comment: Thank you! Great tip! Will note that this is slower.

Answer (score 3):

```
var result = root.Elements("topNode")
                 .Elements("middleNode")
                 .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("filteringAttribute") == "filterValue")
                 .Elements("penultimateNode")
                 .Where(a => (string)a.Attribute("anotherFilterAttribute") == "somethingElse")
                 .Elements("nodesIWantReturned");
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be safer to use .Elements instead of .Descendants for the first three node selections? .Descendents could reach too far if the content of nodesIWantReturned has a match?