# LINQ to XML equivalent of XPath

Tags: c#, xpath, linq-to-xml

I have code which parses XML that looks like this:

```
<custom_fields>
  <custom_field>
      <column_name>foo</column_name>
    <column_value>0</column_value>
  <description>Submitted</description>
    <data_type>BOOLEAN</data_type>
    <length>0</length>
    <decimal>0</decimal>
  </custom_field>
  <custom_field>
    <column_name>bar</column_name>
    <column_value>0</column_value>
    <description>Validated</description>
    <data_type>BOOLEAN</data_type>
    <length>0</length>
    <decimal>0</decimal>
  </custom_field>
</custom_fields>
... more <custom_field> elements...
```

I want to find the element called `custom_field` which has a child element called `column_name` with a certain value (for example `bar`), and then find that child's sibling called `column_value` and get its value.  Right now I use XPath on an `XMlDocument` to do this:

```
string path = "//custom_fields/custom_field[column_name='" + key + "']";
XmlNode xNode = doc.SelectSingleNode(path);
if (xNode != null)
{
    XmlNode v = xNode.SelectSingleNode("column_value");
    val.SetValue(v.InnerText);
}
```

Where `key` is the name of the field I am looking for.

But I want to do this using the new LINQ to XML syntax on an `XDocument`.  My thinking is that I will move much of my old-style XPath parsing to the LINQ methods.  Maybe it's not a good idea, but this is a case where if I can get it to work, then I believe I will have a much better understanding of LINQ in general, and will be able to clean up a lot of complex code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use XPath with XElement or LINQ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642829/how-to-use-xpath-with-xelement-or-linq)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always use XPath within LINQ to XML.  Just include the `System.Xml.XPath` namespace.

```
var xpath = $"//custom_fields/custom_field[column_name='{key}']/column_value";
var columnValue = doc.XPathSelectElement(xpath);
if (columnValue != null)
{
    val.SetValue((int)columnValue);
}
```

Otherwise for the equivalent LINQ to XML query:

```
var columnValue = doc.Descendants("custom_fields")
    .Elements("custom_field")
    .Where(cf => (string)cf.Element("column_name") == key) // assuming `key` is a string
    .Elements("column_value")
    .SingleOrDefault();
```

Comment: I think the top answer will be an XPath injection issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your XQuery expression

```
//custom_fields/custom_field[column_name='key']
```

selects all `custom_field` elements in `custom_fields` elements where the value of the `column_key` child element equals `"key"`. You expect a single element to be returned and select the value of the `column_value` child element.

You can express this using LINQ to XML as follows:

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(...);

var query = from fields in doc.Descendants("custom_fields")
            from field in fields.Elements("custom_field")
            where (string)field.Element("column_name") == "key"
            select (int)field.Element("column_value");

int result = query.Single();
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to find the element called
>   custom_field which has a child element
>   called column_name with a certain
>   value (for example "bar", and then
>   find that child's sibling called
>   column_value and get its value.

Use:

```
/custom_fields/custom_field[column_name = 'bar']/column_value
```

Comment: Using XPathSelectElement