# How can i replace tags in xml using c#

Tags: c#, xml, tags

I would like to replace XML tag values in C#.
Here is some sample XML:

```
<Dr.Watson>
 <Bugs>
  <Bug Name="Bug.add --> AAAAAAAAAAAA">
    <criteria>
      <includeFilterSets>
        <filterSet>
          <filter>
            <filterName>PRODUCT_NAME</filterName>
            <operator>
              <name>Equals</name>
            </operator>
            <value>Dr.Watson</value>
          </filter>
        </filterSet>
      </includeFilterSets>
      <grouping>
        <groupBy>
          <name>STATUS</name>
        </groupBy>
      </grouping>
      <caseSensitive>false</caseSensitive>
      <entityToSearch>
        <name>BUG</name>
      </entityToSearch>
    </criteria>
  </Bug>
 </Bugs>
</Dr.Watson>
```

I would like to replace the tag `<name>STATUS</name>` under `<groupBy>` tag.

Here is my existing code:

```
XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_InputFile);
XElement one = xdoc1.Descendants("/Dr.watson/Bugs/Bug/grouping/groupBy").First();
one.SetAttributeValue("name", "ID"); xdoc1.Save(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_InputFile);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of downvotes. I would suggest letting us know what you have already tried. We are here to help, not write code for you.

Comment: @TheWaxMann here is the code i have so far:XDocument xdoc1 = XDocument.Load(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_InputFile);
                XElement one = xdoc1.Descendants("/Dr.watson/Bugs/Bug/grouping/groupBy").First();
                one.SetAttributeValue("name", "ID");
                xdoc1.Save(FilePath_EXPRESS_API_InputFile);

Comment: Thank you, I have edited your question to contain the code. The people that downvoted it will hopefully remove their downvotes and give you some help with it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `<name>STATUS</name>` is not an attribute, it's an element.
Therefore you should use [SetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setvalue.aspx) method to change its value.

Second, you can't use XPath in`Descendants` method. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642829/how-to-use-xpath-with-xelement-or-linq) for alternatives.