# System.Xml.XPath in Universal Windows Platform

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, uwp

According to MSDN, Extensions class in System.Xml.XPath should be available for Universal Windows Platform (Windows 10):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.extensions(v=vs.110).aspx

However in default configuration not even the System.Xml.XPath namespace is available.
The compiler and IntelliSense doesn't find it and even Resharper is unable to find the missing reference - although according to MSDN it should be in System.Xml.Linq.dll. (I can use LINQ without any problem)

Also in the reference manager I was unable to find a fitting assembly.

With some research I've found this official System.Xml.XPath package on NuGet:
https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Xml.XPath/

However this does not contain the Extension class (and thus the XPathSelectElement extension method) either. (But at least the other XPath classes)

Am I doing something wrong or this is an error in the documentation and none of these classes are available for Windows 10?

Edit:
Things I've already done:

- Visual Studio restart
- Windows restart
- Test on a different computer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, it turned out that you have to add the **System.Xml.XPath.XDocument** Package with Nuget.
It is a bit unfortunate that this is so undocumented on MSDN.

Credit goes to winffee on MSDN Social:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/46cc17ce-b562-4089-be9c-dd5aa53b36de/systemxmlxpath-in-universal-windows-platform?forum=wpdevelop

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to get the `System.Xml.XPath` Nuget package (as you referenced in your question):

[image: System.Xml.Linq reference manager screengrab]

This will add the assembly and the proper refernce, and then add the proper `using` declaration (needs to be there in addition to `System.Xml.Linq`):

```
using System.Xml.XPath;
```

[image: sample XPathEval]

This will also allow for `XPathSelectElement` (not depicted, but working in my environment).

Comment: This does not help - VS cannot find any System.Xml.Linq assembly targeting .NET for Windows Universal.
You've probably tried it with a normal windows application. (I assume that because of the project name: ConsoleApplication1) But this is about Universal Windows Platform which is a somewhat restricted subset of the full .net framework.
Anyways, thank you for your answer!

Comment: Are you sure, you've added only this package? Unfortunately this is not working for me...

Comment: Positive.  This was done on an otherwise fresh install of Windows 10/VS 2015.

Answer (score 0):

To enable XPath extensions in UWP applications you can add the following nuget package

System.Xml.XPath.XmlDocument => for XMLDocument processing

System.Xml.XPath.XDocument   => for XDocument processing.