# Behavior of LoadXml and SelectNodes

Tags: c#, xml, .net-3.5, xmldocument, selectnodes

I have code similar to the first below

```
String xml1 =
    @"<resultset>
        <result>
            <alamakota />
        </result>
    </resultset>";
String xml2 =
    @"<resultset/>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml1);
XmlNodeList nodes1 = xDoc.SelectNodes("/resultset/result");
xDoc.LoadXml(xml2);
XmlNodeList nodes2 = xDoc.SelectNodes("/resultset/result");
Console.WriteLine(nodes1.Count);
Console.WriteLine(nodes2.Count);
```

I would expect that WriteLine methods gives 1 and 0 but not always. In normal program run it will give double 0. Also during debug when I put breakpoint on second SelectNodes and check value of nodes1.Count in VS it gives me 1 and 0 at the end. It seems that SelectNodes is evaluated during first check of XmlNodeList and not in line where it is in code, for example code below will give 1 and 0 every time it runs

```
String xml1 =
    @"<resultset>
        <result>
            <alamakota />
        </result>
    </resultset>";
String xml2 =
    @"<resultset/>";
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xml1);
XmlNodeList nodes1 = xDoc.SelectNodes("/resultset/result");
Int32 c1 = nodes1.Count;
xDoc.LoadXml(xml2);
XmlNodeList nodes2 = xDoc.SelectNodes("/resultset/result");
Console.WriteLine(nodes1.Count);
Console.WriteLine(nodes2.Count);
```

I know that I can do xDoc = new XmlDocument() after first SelectNodes and it will work like expected but I wonder if this is how it should work because I can't find this scenario at msdn. If yes then why? Please point me to some documentation.

Comment: Out of interest, is there any reason you can't use LINQ to XML? That's generally a rather cleaner API for dealing with XML...

Comment: Technically no. It's my choice because I use XPath in other systems where LINQ is unavailable.

Comment: @pen2 - you can use XPath with LINQ to XML.  See for instance [How to use XPath with XElement or LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642829/how-to-use-xpath-with-xelement-or-linq).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is documented.

From the documentation from [`XmlNodeList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnodelist(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Changes to the children of the node object that the `XmlNodeList` collection was created from are **immediately** reflected in the nodes returned by the `XmlNodeList` properties and methods.

And from the documentation for [`XmlNode.SelectNodes()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The `XmlNodeList` object returned by this method will be valid while the underlying document remains unchanged. **If the underlying document changes, unexpected results may be returned (no exception will be thrown).**

So, when you overwrite the contents of `xDoc` with completely new XML, the contents of a previously created `XmlNodeList` are no longer defined by Microsoft.