# How to select specific XML child with a given attribute

Tags: c#, xml

There is a xml document with content below:

```
    <Bookshop>
        <Book id="isbn-001"/>
        <Pen id="num-001" />
    </Bookshop>
```

I want to search the child nodes through the special id value, and the child node type is uncertain.

If the child nodes with same name/type, we can do it:[select child with given attribute](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5f16af14-00f7-49a7-8fa9-4ae1f6e96410/how-to-select-specific-xml-child-with-a-given-attribute-in-c-dataset-dataview?forum=aspwebforms)

```
 XmlNodeList nodelist = doc.SelectNodes("parent/child/node[@attribute='True']");
```

But in above xml, the child nodes aren't same name/type, should I do a loop method? Is there any select nodes method I can use. Thanks

Comment: I think this can help you https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2db9013e-3c60-477e-89ef-3f791144fc73/correct-way-to-get-child-node-values-from-xml?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: You can use an XPath expression with the wildcard `*` to select the required elements: `".//*[@id='isbn-001']"` to recursively search the entire document, or `/Bookshop/*[@id='isbn-001']` if `<Bookshop>` is the root node. See [What is the difference between .// and //* in XPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35606708) and [How to use XPath with XElement or LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3642829).